# Not same src when append images

Tags: jquery, append, setinterval

I have this jquery programation

```
$(window).load(function() {

    var leng = 24;
    var long = 0;
    var rm = Math.floor(Math.random()*leng);



    var tmr = self.setInterval(
        function() {
            var rm = Math.floor(Math.random()*leng);
            var valor = "xxxxx/" +rm+ ".jpg";

            $( "#imacon" ).append( "<img src="+valor+" />" );

            long++;
            if(long == 10) { 
                window.clearInterval(tmr);
            }
        }, 500)         
});
```

How can append images without same src? (the images append radomly)

Comment: Make an array of all the images. Select an image randomly, append it to the DOM, and remove it from the array. Repeat....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of available choices and when one is used, then remove it from the remaining choices to use:

```
$(window).load(function() {

    var leng = 24;
    var long = 0;

    // create choices array
    var choices = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < leng; i++) {
        choices.push(i);
    }

    var tmr = setInterval(function() {
        var rm = Math.floor(Math.random()*choices.length);

        // get random choice
        var num = choices[rm];

        // remove this item from choices array
        choices.splice(rm, 1);

        var valor = "xxxxx/" +num+ ".jpg";

        $( "#imacon" ).append( "<img src="+valor+" />" );

        long++;
        if(long === 10 || choices.length === 0) { 
            clearInterval(tmr);
        }
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: And if the src of the images are in different folders?

Comment: @MateoSuarez - If the paths are all the asme, you just put the path in front of the `valor` part when you're constructing the URL.  If all your images have different paths, then you construct an array of URLs and put that in the choices array to start with and then just pull the whole URL out of the choices array rather than just a number.

Comment: Can you help me with that part? I simply don't know how do that

Comment: @MateoSuarez - Do all images use the same path?